# How do I keybind functions to keys in the keyboard with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I want to make a function that is triggered by pressing a button with the 
command (`b = Button(command = a)`) that will also be able to accept calls from the bind command. The problem is that the bind command sends a variable (event) while command does not. another problem that I have is that I can't figure out how to link functions to physical key pressing on the computer

I have tried `b.bind('a',func)` to link the physical keys and checked the binding with the enter key

```
from tkinter import *
def func():
    print("meow")

main = Tk()
bRoll = Button(text = "Hello", command = func)
bRoll.bind('r',func)
bRoll.bind('<Enter>',func)
bRoll.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

That did not seem to work as it did nothing and I tried to bind to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (`<Enter>`) to see what happens and it printed an error because it wanted to send an event to `func` and it couldn't accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. It does not make any sense to bind a button to an event. Basically what you want is that when you press a key, `func()` should be called. For that, in this example, you need to bind the event to the main window as in `main.bind('r' ,func)`.
2. To consume the `event`, you can add it as a parameter and initialise
   it to `None`. Also note that `<Enter>` means whenever your mouse pointer *enters* the button widget and not the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. To bind the Enter key, you need to use `<Return>`.

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   def func(event=None):
       tk.Label(main, text="Meow").pack()

   main = tk.Tk()
   bRoll = tk.Button(text = "Hello", command = func)
   main.bind('r',func)
   bRoll.bind('<Enter>',func)
   bRoll.pack()

   main.mainloop()
   ```

[image: Demo]

Note that in the demo above, initially I had pressed the key <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to access the same (one)function with the mouse button and keyboard too.
I just did

```
entery. bind(("<Return>") ,lambda event:function_name().focus())
```

and it worked.

Comment: Why is there a `.focus()`? Also you don't need the brackets around `"<Return>"`.